# How do I print a price depending on the dropdown value that is selected?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this table with the following headers: Product, Quantity, Price/Kg, Total

The cells in the column "Product" are all dropdown lists with the products the company offers and the "Price/Kg" are TextInputs.

I want to print the designated price onto the TextInput, depending on the dropdown's value.

I have this subroutine, but it doesn't do anything:

```
Sub getPreco()

Select Case ActiveDocument.FormFields("produtos").DropDown.Value
    Case "Amêijoas Vietnamitas"
        ActiveDocument.FormFields("TextBox1").TextInput.Result = "1 euro"
    Case "Gambas"
        ActiveDocument.FormFields("TextBox1").TextInput.Result = "2 euros"
    Case Else
        ActiveDocument.FormFields("TextBox1").TextInput.Clear
        MsgBox "Price not yet defined"

End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any VBA for this. All you need do is check the dropdown formfield's 'Calculate on Exit' property and employ a formula field coded along the lines of:

```
{IF{REF produtos}= "Amêijoas Vietnamitas" "€1" {IF{REF produtos}= "Gambas" "€2" "Preco ainda nao definido"}}
```

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub getPreco()

Select Case ActiveDocument.FormFields("produtos").DropDown.Value
    Case 1
        ActiveDocument.FormFields("Texto1").Result = "1 euro"
    Case 2
        ActiveDocument.FormFields("Texto1").Result = "2 euros"
    Case Else
        ActiveDocument.FormFields("Texto1").TextInput.Clear
        MsgBox "Preco ainda nao definido"

End Select
End Sub
```